# Drawing multiple rectangles using SurfaceView and Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, queue, draw, surfaceview

I am trying to draw multiple rectangles using a SurfaceView. My simple project is based on the LunarLanding example from the Android samples.

Here is my code:

```
public CustomSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    objQueue = new LinkedList<CustomObject>();  
    ..
}

// This is called from a different place, new data is sent multiple times/second
public void updateData(float width, float length) {
    CustomObject myObj = new CustomObject(width, length);
    Log.e(TAG, "[updateData]: " + myObj.width + " " + myObj.length);

    if (objQueue == null) { // this is always null, adding object to queue is never executed
      return;
    }

    objQueue.add(myObj);
    Log.e(TAG, "[updateData]: objQueue.size(): " + objQueue.size());
}


private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      canvas.drawPaint(paint);

      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
      LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "[doDraw]"); // works fine until here

      Iterator it = objQueue.iterator();
      Log.e(TAG, "[doDraw]: queue size: " + objQueue.size()); // always = 0, object is never drawn..

      while (it.hasNext()) {
        CustomObject myObj = (CustomObject) it.next();
        canvas.drawRect(...);
        Log.e(TAG, "[doDraw]: CustomObject: " + myObj.width + " " + myObj.length);
      }
}
```

I have added some comments in the code, the problem is that the queue is always null, even though I create it when the view is initialized. The draw method never draws the rectangles because the queue is always empty. The strange thing is that the data is received successfully.

If I change the updateData to:

```
if (objQueue == null) {
    objQueue = new LinkedList<CustomObject>();
}
```

Each time a new queue is created and in the draw method still prints out size = 0 and doesn't draw the rectangles.

Basically I have a listener where I get data multiple times/second and I want to draw some simple rectangles at the position that is sent via the listener. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Full code is located here: https://gist.github.com/iRazvan/399fd702ae7704742198

Comment: Have you tries debugging your code to see if `CustomSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor is called? You will need to initialize your queue in all other constructor that you have.

Comment: Yes, that part is called.

Comment: Can you put the whole code for the `CustomSurfaceView` class?

Comment: Ok, I have added link to the code. Also, I have declared the queue static and changed it to a LinkedBlockingQueue and it works. The issue is that objects never seem to be removed from the list. I think using a non-synchronizable structure that is synchronized by me might do the trick.. any suggestions?

Comment: I do not see you calling `poll()` or `remove()` on the queue

Comment: Can I add that as an answer?